# Ideal and Efficient Way of Handling User Logins with Multiple Types (i.e. Employee, Client, etc.)?

Tags: database-design, foreign-key, primary-key, users, logins

I'm developing a database where I will have two types of users:  Employee and Client.  I'm thinking it would be ideal to just have one big `USERS TABLE` with a `user_ID` as PK and `Type` column to distinguish whether the user is an `Employee` or a `Client`.  This is to make it more convenient when a user logs-in where it will only check one table:  `USERS TABLE` for `username` and `password`

However, I realized that this means I would be losing the opportunity to have separate ID's as PK for Employees and Clients (`employee_ID` and `client_ID`).

Would having another table called `EMPLOYEE TABLE` and `CLIENT TABLE` (that have `user_ID_FK` as FK, `employee_ID` or `client_ID` respectively) be ideal or would that de-normalize the tables?

How best to handle user log-in where there are multiple different types of users (Employee, Client, etc.)?

Comment: Is there data related to an employee or a client that is unique to that category? (example: you might need an emergency contact for an employee, and not need one for a customer). If there's data unique to the type of person, then having tables that contain the columns that only pertain to one type of user is reasonable. Also: can an employee also be a client? Should they have separate accounts if that's true? Again separate tables make sense; in fact, in that case, you may want to rethink having a `user` table; as you need to ensure that each user is tied to one and only one user category.